# Shopware customer import error: The EntityManager is closed

Tags: php, mysql, shopware

While importing bulk customer into Shopware only the first row from the CSV imported then throws the error

> "The EntityManager is closed".

If I try with only single data it imports the customer but also throws the same error "The EntityManager is closed".

Checked the `core_production_date.log` and `importexport.log` in `shopware/var/log/` no log there.

Also checked `Configureation->logfile`, nothing there too.

How can I get the actual error log why it's happening? Please let me know if anybody can help.

**Shopware version is 5.2.27**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The EntityManager is closed happens when the Database Context of the request was closed due to some SQL Exception.
In my project this happened while using the Resource API of Shopware which might also be used by the Importer. The Resource catches the error so it won't show in the logs. The entity manager is closed though by doctrine because of the SQL error and cannot be reopened in the same request. So any call after that will end up with the "EntityManager is closed" message.

It helps if you find a way to run the import in console where the error will be at least shown as a console log. You can also have a look at the Resource itself to see what kind of data might be wrong or missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try..catch and reset the EntityManager in the catch clause, if it's closed (you should extend you API Class from ), eg:

```
try {
 ... you code ...
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    if (!$this->getManager()->isOpen()) {
        $this->resetEntityManager();
    }
...
}
```